# How can I remove inline keyboard after click?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My bot sends a pick with 2 inline callback buttons: like / dislike. After a user clicks on like or dislike button, I want this inline keyboard to disappear.

This is how I make a dislike button

```
 dislike_button =types.InlineKeyboardButton (text=emojize("Dislike :broken_heart:", use_aliases=True), callback_data='dislike')
    keyboard.add(dislike_button)
```

And this is how handle click on this button

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):

   if call.data == 'dislike':
      bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='you disliked it!')
```

How can I make this buttons to disappear after the click? Or how can I make impossible to click on this like or dislike button again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you are using telebot, one option could be using **one_time_keyboard=True** parameter to hide button once it's clicked.

```
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to edit the message.
Use the method [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup)

Send reply_markup parameter as null.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js telegraf to remove inline keyboard:

```js
await context.editMessageReplyMarkup(undefined);
```